# Android. Своя кнопка в меню "поделиться"

Tags: java, android

Новичок в андроидинге.
Помогите, плиз, сообразить, что-то информации нет совсем. Хочу добавить свою  кнопку в меню "поделиться" при просмотре фото (там, где вставляют свои кнопки всякие контактики, яндекс диски и пр.). Помогите, плиз, кто чем может, примером или ссылкой на маны (а лучше оба варианта). Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @Роман Чижиков, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что Вам нужно в Манифесте указать, что Ваше приложение умеет работать с изображениями. Вот ссылка на документацию с примерами. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Receiving

Answer (score 5):

Мне известна пара вариантов. В своём приложении делаю так - на кнопку меню в ActionBare повесил вот этот код:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
String textToSend="some text";
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textToSend);
try
{
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Описание действия"));
}
catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Выглядит так:

[image]

Либо можно сделать, как в доках написано: [ссылка](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/sharing/shareaction.html).

Примерно так, уверен, можно и картинки отправлять, если изменить в приведённом выше коде

```
intent.setType("text/plain");
```

значение "text/plain".

А вообще в гугле я это в своё время довольно быстро нашёл. )

Comment: Не то. Спрашивается, как добавить в этот список свое приложение. @Lucky_spirit ответил то что надо.

Comment: @metalurgus, да... То ли я не выспался, то ли вопрос неясно сформулирован)

Comment: Что такое intent.setType("text/plain"); ?

Comment: Это тип контента которым делишься если кратко